# Android widget sizing: Is the height of a single cell 80dp or 40dp?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding some of the google documentation. Specifically, [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html#anatomy_determining_size) suggests that for widgets 1 cell has a height and width of 40dp, 110dp for 2 cells etc.

In practice however, it seems that I can set my minHeight and Width as high as 80dp before my widget switches from being a 1x1 widget to a 2x2 widget. Does anyone know how to explain this variation? (And for that matter why your first cell in the documentation is 40dp, but if you want to occupy 2 cells, you have more than twice the space?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If you're referring to launcher cells, the values change (depending on grid size in different launchers.

For normal launchers, these are the dp per cell.

1   40dp

2   110dp

3   180dp

4   250dp

n   70 × n − 30

Source: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html

Comment: I have seen the link and referenced it in my post. This makes sense, but in practice, my widget seems to be able to be 80dip x 80dip before it occupies 2 cells. I am trying to understand why it changes at 80 instead of 40 like the documentation seems to suggest it should

Comment: My best guess is that the values specified in the table refer to ideal cell sizes. 80 dp is the threshold between the 1 and 2 cell boundary (the 110dp for 2 cells is not a minimum, it is the middle of the dp range for 2 cells).

What does the widget look like 80 x 80 dp?

Comment: it more or less fills the grid cell space. It seems odd to me that they would tell you 40dp when you actually have 80? It also seems odd that 2 cells are much more than twice as wide as 1 cell? It seems like there is a flaw in my understanding ... no?

Comment: If I am reading it correctly, those are the minimum sizes for that number of cells. So the *minimum* size for one cell is 40dp. The *minimum* size for two cells is 110dp. So at 80dp, you're below the minimum size for two cells, and so are in one.